# Where is the latest document of Erratic Simulation?

Tags: ros, erratic, erratic-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/TeleopErraticSimulation

I got an error by running : rosmake erratic_gazebo teleop_base

```
 sam@/home/sam/code/ros/gazebo/stl$ rosmake erratic_gazebo teleop_base
 [ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['erratic_gazebo', 'teleop_base']                                                              
 [ rosmake ] Logging to      directory/home/sam/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110731-113912                                              
 [ rosmake ] Expanded args ['erratic_gazebo', 'teleop_base'] to:
 []                                                                 
 [ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or      packages: ['erratic_gazebo', 'teleop_base']               
 [ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack      names.                                                 
 
 sam@/home/sam/code/ros/gazebo/stl$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10774/where-is-the-latest-document-of-erratic-simulation?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-07-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-08-01**:
Isn't it would be install with original installation of ROS?I use "ROS version-*" to install every packges.

**Comment by [Bram van de Klundert](https://answers.ros.org/users/392/bram-van-de-klundert/) on 2011-08-01**:
are you sure you have those packages on your pc and in a location where ros commands can find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/264/erratic_gazebo-tutorial-not-working). Instead of installing the CTurtle version of `erratic_robot stack`, install Diamondback version by running `sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-erratic-robot` if you are running ROS Diamondback.

Note: I have also updated the linked tutorial to use `erratic_robot` stack to prevent future confusion.

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2011-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1